# Can I create a SQL Server instance programmatically using C#?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to create a SQL Server instance using C#. I need to be able to write the C# code to do this.

Comment: When you say create an instance do you mean connect to a server programatically to perform some work or do you actually mean physically create (i.e. install) an instance?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. But you'll want to do it by using the installer's [command prompt options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Use the [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx) method to launch the installer, passing the appropriate path to the setup file and the correct command line parameters:

```
var installer = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"d:\setup.exe", "/q .....");
installer.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: If you have an application that downloads a version of SQL Express installer, can you pass these params to the installer application or will I need to extract the installer files, first, and then execute this command against setup.exe?